# How can use FTP in OBEX to deleting and copying a file into destination Device via bluetooth java code?

Tags: ftp, bluetooth, copy, delete-file, obex

I need to replace a file with old version of it in destination device via bluetooth.
I know that OBEX(FTP and OPP) profiles is necessary to use for this.
But I don't know How can delete old version and copy new version of file in destination directory (java code).

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

To perform operations on files you whould firstly change to the directory where the file is.
For exampe, if you need to get to /root/directory/subdir/
you should call setPath three times

```
    setPath(""); // to get to /root/
    setPath("directory") // get to /root/directory/
    setPath("subdir") // get to root/directory/subdir/
```

All the code written below is for J2ME
I use this method to set the path with separators (e.g. /root/dir/)

```
    private void moveToDirectory(String dir) throws IOException {
        RE r = new RE("/"); // where RE is me.regexp.RE
        setDir("");
        String[] dirs = r.split(dir);
        for (int i = 1; i < dirs.length; i++) setDir(dirs[i]);
    }
```

To delete a file you should open a PUT operation on it and close it, or use the delete method in ClientSession.

```
    public void delete() throws IOException {
        HeaderSet hs = cs.createHeaderSet(); // where cs is an opened ClientSession
        hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, file); // file - is a filename String, no slashes should be used
        cs.delete(hs);
    }
```

If you need to replace a file you probably don't need to call delete method, just open OutputStream and write to it a new one

```
    public OutputStream openOutputStream() throws IOException {
        HeaderSet hs = cs.createHeaderSet();
        hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, file);
        Operation op = cs.put(hs); // Operation should be global, so you can close it after you done
        return op.openOutputStream();
    }
```

remember to close Operation after you done with the streams.